conditional CICD with shared directories in monorepo
I have a bun monorepo structured similarly to
root/
    apps/
        app1/
        app2/
        app3/
    shared/
        lib1/
        lib2/
        lib3/

where I build and deploy apps 1 through 3 via GitHub Actions triggered off pushes to release branches, but all three use 0 or more of the shared/lib packages.
Currently I listen for changes in apps/** and re-deploy accordingly, but any change/commits that only affect shared/** I manually run the CICD.
I want to be able to dynamically build and deploy my apps depending on the shared/** folder as well
In my mind there are 2 options to automate deployment from changes -only- in shared/**-

Re-deploy everything if shared/** changes at all (brute force, guaranteed, but more expensive)
Build every app every time, but only deploy if there are changes between current and new versions. (slightly more efficient, but need a reliable hashing or comparison tool)

Is there a third (or fourth) option I am missing?

We are using Bun workspaces and Typescript references to import from other packages from the monorepo.
Bun is used to build each app
.github/workflows/workflow.yml has the following lines inside -

pull_request: 
    branches: 
        - main 
    paths: 
        - "apps/**" 
        - "shared/**" 
push: 
    branches: 
        - main 
    paths: 
        - "apps/**" 
        - "shared/**" 

